# 1.44" tft display arduino white screen

Tags: arduino, display, arduino-c++

I'm trying to get a 1.44" TFT display working with the Arduino Mega 2560. I've tried a couple libraries, and tried using some example code, but no matter what I do and how I wire it I end up with a totally white screen.

Wiring:

- VCC - 3.3V
- GND - GND
- CS  - 8
- RESET - 9
- A0 - 8
- SDA - 20
- SCK - 52

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqBxj.jpg)

[board and screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c25o.jpg)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <TFT_ILI9163C.h>

#define CS 10
#define DC 9

#define WHITE   0xFFFF

TFT_ILI9163C tft = TFT_ILI9163C(CS, 8, DC);  

void setup() {
tft.begin();
tft.fillScreen();
}

 void loop(){
  text();
  delay(500);
 }

 unsigned long text() {

tft.setCursor(29, 63);
tft.setTextColor(WHITE);  
tft.setTextSize(1);
tft.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different color for your text? I'm not sure what color tft.fillScreen() uses, but if it fills the screen with white, and your text color is white, it sounds like things might be working correctly?

Comment: Tried changing the text color, still just a white display

Comment: This might be better suited for [arduino.se] instead, as it is partially about the board and wiring.

Comment: The wiring in your post doesn't match the code. And the constructor for TFT_ILI9163C seems to confuse the pins. So what wiring and code are you using?